# (Delphi) how to prevent DB controls from editing the record

Tags: delphi

I have a form with a grid with data and some db controls (DBEdit for instance).
When user types inside the DBEdit, Delphi automatically set the record in edit mode. But I dont like this, I want to be able to edit a record only if I programmatically call Table.Edit;

any idea how to prevent this? of course without setting the edit control read-only. I mean a workaround in the data aware components (table) directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `AutoEdit` property  of your datasource to `false`.
DBNavigator provides a nbEdit Button.

Answer (score 3):

Look up `TDataSource.AutoEdit` property.